# enum error: unresolved name

Tags: enums, rust

Enum constructors defined in the same file no longer resolve.

```
enum Mode {
    Global,
    Local,
}

fn which_mode() -> Mode {
    Global
}

fn main() {
    match which_mode() {
        Global => println!("Global"),
        Local  => println!("Local"),
    }
}
```

The compiler gives an error "unresolved name `Global`" in the function `which_mode`.  When I qualify it as `Mode::Global`, it works.  Now, it thinks that the `Global` in the `match` statement is a binding, and is hence irrefutable!

This behaviour is recent -- the nightly of 11 November successfully compiled the above code.  With this current behaviour being how it is, why do `Some`, `Ok`, *etc.* not need qualified paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noticed, [very recently](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/18973), enums changed to have the [variants scoped with their type name](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0390-enum-namespacing.md).

The standard library has [explicit reexports of the variants](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b825b3496aff1ed784f7a7ca935245208b95aabb/src/libcore/option.rs#L146) so they are available adjacent to the type (e.g. for the precise example linked there `core::option::None` is an alias for `core::option::Option::None`), which is why they're available unqualified in their module.

However, there's a trick here: `None`, `Some`, `Err`, `Ok` are only available by default because [they are in](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b825b3496aff1ed784f7a7ca935245208b95aabb/src/libstd/prelude.rs#L74) the prelude, which is imported by default into every module. That is, the namespacing changes didn't change why those variants do not need qualification in most Rust code.

Comment: In fact, it took me a few minutes to understand that Rust was treating the `Global` in the `match` as a binding.  I sometimes wish that Rust made a distinction (_a la_ Erlang, but opposite in specifics) between **initial** lower-case vs. upper-case of the name when trying to bind: upper-case means enum (no binding); lower-case means binding.

Comment: I faced with the same error I can't understand from the documentation how to get sigma.ml's example to work. How to do that?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp : To make the example work, please qualify **all** `enum` instances.  Change `Global` to `Mode::Global` and `Local` to `Mode::Local`.  It is important to change **all** occurrences.